# trying to save an HTML table into a JS array. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

thank you in advance for your time and energy. i want to save the contents of my HTML table into a javascript array. Any advice on my method for looping through the table to attempt to extract its contents would be appreciated. i will include all my relevant code.

i have an HTML table

```
var table = '';
    var letterArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];
    var rows = 21;
    var cols = 11;
    var selectedCell;
    var returnedID;
    var tableArray = [];

    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        table += '<tr>';

        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            if (c == 0)
            {
                if (r == 0)
                {
                    var cellID = r.toString();
                    cellID += letterArray[c - 1];
                    table += '<td style="min-width:50px; height:25px;">' + '</td>';
                }
                else
                {
                    var cellID = r.toString();
                    cellID += letterArray[c - 1];
                    table += '<td style="min-width:50px; height:25px">' + r + '</td>';
                }

            }
            else if (r == 0 && c > 0)
            {
                var cellID = r.toString();
                cellID += letterArray[c - 1];
                table += '<td style="min-width:50px; height:25px">' + letterArray[c - 1] + '</td>';

            }
            else
            {
                var cellID = r.toString();
                cellID += letterArray[c - 1];
                table += '<td id="' + cellID + '" style="min-width:50px; height:25px;" onclick="selectCell(this)">' + '</td>';
            }

        }

        table += '</tr>';
    }

    //write the table to the document
    document.write('<table id="table" border=1>' + table + '</table>');
```

then i have a function which selects a cell

```
function selectCell(x)
    {
        var currentSelection = document.querySelector('.selected');

        if (currentSelection)
        {
            currentSelection.classList.remove('selected');
        }

        x.classList.add('selected');

        var selectedCellID = x.parentNode.rowIndex.toString();
        selectedCellID += String.fromCharCode((x.cellIndex - 1) + 65);

        returnedID = selectedCellID;
    }
```

then a function which enters a value into the cell from a text box

```
function textEnter()
    {
        var input = document.getElementById("txtField").value;
        document.getElementById(returnedID).innerText = input;
        document.getElementById("txtField").value = '';
    }
```

here is my problem: i want to save this table into an array. here is my attempt:

```
function save()
    {
        alert("inside save()");
        var tableData = document.getElementById("table");

        var current, cell;

        for (var i = 0; (current = tableData.rows[i]) ; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; (cell = current.cells[j]); j++)
            {
                tableArray.push(cell[j].innerText);
            }
        }

        localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(tableArray));
    }
```

finally i have a function which is just trying to test my array success or failure by alerting the length of the array

```
function test()
    {
        alert(tableArray.length.toString());
    }
```

after entering som data in my table and running my save() function, then checking it with my test() function, it returns an array length of 0. so i am missing something in the conversion from the html data to the table. any advice appreciated. thank you for your time and energy again

Comment: With `cell = current.cells[j]` inside the save function you are already getting a reference to the cell, then do `cell.innerText`, not `cell[j].`

Comment: ah! thank you. will make that change and continue working. appreciate your time thanks a lot